# Como utilizar o comando "LOAD DATA INFILE"?

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

É o seguinte galera, eu tenho um banco e nele uma tabela chamada "pessoas" a qual contém "id_pessoas" como atributo e eu quero fazer como teste uma importação de informações utilizando esse comando do título, já tenho salvo um arquivo excel no formato ".csv" da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

http://blog.professorulisses.com/index.php/2015/05/20/importacao-de-dados-do-excel-para-o-mysql/ : Neste artigo o autor ensina utilizar mas não deixa claro como indicar o caminho em que o arquivo se encontra, alguém poderia dar um help e me explicar os parâmetros?

Comment: Eu acho que está escrito nesta linha: `Próximo passo é executar o comando de importação do MySQL. LOAD DATA INFILE ‘/TEMP/EXEMPLO.CSV’  INTO TABLE TEM_CLIENTE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘;’ (NOME,SEXO, DT_NASC);`

Comment: Sendo que `/TEMP/EXEMPLO.CSV` é o caminho do arquivo. que voce coloca aonde está o seu arquivo.

Comment: Fica mostrando erro quando executo este comando: LOAD DATA INFILE `C:\Users\Wallace\Desktop\atividade\dadoss.csv`  INTO TABLE `pessoas_documento` FIELDS TERMINATED BY `;` (idPessoas);

Comment: Qual erro que é apresentado?

Comment: "Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '`C:\Users\Wallace\Desktop\atividade\dadoss.csv`  INTO TABLE `pessoas_documento` ' na linha 1"

Answer (score 1):

Consegui utilizando o comando desta forma:

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:Users/Wallace/Desktop/atividade/dados.txt' INTO TABLE pessoas;